# Python Refresh GUI to create another output

Tags: python, tkinter, smartsheet-api

I am very new to Python. I am trying to create an app that printing a number from a Smartsheet sheet then delete it. The problem is I only can print it once, once I click "Create" button again, it gives error message. I believe when I click "Create" button again, it returns the deleted number from the sheet. Thank you!

```
{"response": {"statusCode": 404, "reason": "Not Found", "content": {"detail": {"ids": [3462338204985220], "type": "row"}, "errorCode": 1006, "message": "Not Found", "refId": "hcuqkioxqz46"}}}
```

Here is the sheet that stores a series of number:
[image: Screenshot of sheet that stores a series if number]

Here is my code:

```
#Smartsheet client access token
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet('access token')

#Order Dashboard sheet ID
MySheet=smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)


def conceptnum():
    n=1
    for Myrow in MySheet.rows:
        while n==1:
            for Mycell in Myrow.cells:
                row_ids=Myrow.id
                label1['text']=int(Mycell.value)
                label2['text']="Your concept number is created" 
                smartsheet_client.Sheets.delete_rows(
                sheet_id,                       # sheet_id
                row_ids)     # row_ids
            n=n-1


Height=100
Width=200

root=tk.Tk()

canvas=tk.Canvas(root, height=Height, width=Width)
canvas.pack()

frame=tk.Frame(root, bg="grey")
frame.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.4)

button=tk.Button(root, text="Create",command=conceptnum)
button.pack(side='bottom')

label1=tk.Label(frame,font=15)
label1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1,relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8)

label2=tk.Label(root)
label2.place(relwidth=1,relheight=0.2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently written, your `conceptnum()` function is doing this:

```
for each row in the sheet -> 
  for each cell in the current row ->
    ...
    delete the current row
```

So, if your sheet contains more than one column, your script will:

- get the first row of the sheet
- get the value of the first cell of the row being processed
- delete the row from the sheet
- get the value of the second cell of the row being processed
- delete the row from the sheet -> this **delete row** request (and the subsequent request for each additional column/cell in the row being processed) will return the "Not Found" error -- because that row no longer exists in the sheet -- you deleted it after reading the first cell value.

Assuming that your objective is to read the value in the first cell of the first row of the sheet, and then delete that row from the sheet, here's a function that will do so -- please note that I've changed the function name and variable names to follow Python style convention (lowercase with underscores):

```
def concept_num():

    # get sheet
    my_sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)

    # initialize row_id
    row_id = None

    for row in my_sheet.rows:
        # get the ID of the current (first) row
        row_id = row.id

        # get the Cell object for the first cell of the current (first) row
        cell = row.cells[0]

        # set labels
        label1['text'] = int(cell.value)
        label2['text'] = 'Your concept number is created' 

        # exit the 'for' loop (so that only the first row is processed)
        break

    # delete the row that was just processed
    if row_id != None:
        smartsheet_client.Sheets.delete_rows(sheet_id, row_id)
    else:
        label1['text'] = 'n/a'
        label2['text'] = 'Concept number not found.'
```

**EDIT 4/13/2020:**

You need to fetch the sheet each time the `concept_num` function runs -- so that `my_sheet` reflects the current contents of the sheet (i.e., no longer contains rows that were deleted when the function ran previously). I've updated the code snippet above accordingly (i.e., added the **get sheet** call at the top of the `concept_num` function). I've also added code at the end of the snippet (using an `else`) to update labels accordingly if the sheet contains no more numbers when the **Create** button is clicked.

Comment: Hello Kim, after I tested, it returned the same error message. Is there anything to do with tkinter codes? thank you!

Comment: Sorry about that -- I missed that you need to re-fetch the sheet each time the `concept_num` function runs. I've updated my answer accordingly -- specifically, to move the **get sheet** call `my_sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)` into the `concept_num` function. See the **EDIT 4/13/2020** portion of my updated answer for more details.